# Import not defined in a function

Tags: python

I have the following folder structure:

```
code\Functions\quadrature.py  
code\Functions\proba.py  
code\Example\test.py
```

In **proba.py** I have:

```
def recurCoef(...):

    return ...
```

In **quadrature.py** I have:

```
import Functions as pc2

def quadTens(...):

    coef = pc2.proba.recurCoef(...)
    return ...
```

And finally in **test.py** I have

```
import sys
sys.path.append('../')
import Functions as pc2

test = pc2.quadrature.quadTens(...)
```

When I try to run **test.py** I get the following error:

```
File "..\Functions\quadrature.py", line 21, in quadTens
NameError: name 'recurCoef' is not defined
```

I don't really understand why, I tried to write a script in **quadrature.py** (out of a function) that calls **pc2.proba.recurCoef** then run the file for testing, and it works. So a priori the module has been correctly imported.

Answer (score 1):

You can change your code like this.

```
from code import Functions as pc2
```

or

```
from .. import Functions as pc2
```

Comment: Same problem, it's even worst because the import fails

Comment: Ah, nevermind, I think it works now, after restarting the kernel. I guess it was a bug...